# REST API speed improvement

Tags: node.js, angular

We have a REST Api that we are using on the frontend. It transfers a lot of data around 200 object in a JSON. The REST API we are using load rather quickly in the postman and jmeter. But when displaying data in the frontend it slows down. It takes around 3-5 secs before the data is fully displayed.

Is this a frontend or backend issue? Can I really trust the results from postman and jmeter calls? What can I do to improve this timings? thanks!

Comment: If it loads fast with postman, then it's unlikely it's a back-end issue since the back-end is likely doing the same thing whether the request comes from postman or from your webpage (presumably, both are just requesting and getting the same JSON).  If you show us your front-end code that displays the data, we could offer some thoughts on why it might be slow.

Comment: As always here on Stackoverflow, we can help much more specifically if you show us your actual code (in this case, both front-end and back-end code for the specific request you're measuring).

Comment: If you are familiar with the developer tools in your browser, you can always check in the network tab, how fast the request to the API was. As @jfriend00 noted, it's probably a frontend issue since the API is fast when called from Postman.

Comment: I'm prety sure it's a problem with the frontend. there're no problem that Angular get a large object, the problem is when you try to show it. Try "paginate" the object or use a virtual-scrolling. Check also if you're using binding to a complex function or one property is a "select"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the response! I have confirmed that the issue is from the frontend. It seems our frontend is not yet that optimized in handling large amount of data.